# Checking for installed software with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rbenv

I've put together a simple bash script to see if `rbenv` is installed.  I installed rbenv system-wide instead of per-user [using this guide](http://alexanderzagaynov.com/rbenv-shared-install-on-ubuntu-14-04/) and confirmed it's installed for both users:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ rbenv version
2.1.4 (set by /usr/local/rbenv/version)

user@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~$ rbenv version
2.1.4 (set by /usr/local/rbenv/version)
```

I have to check if it is installed for the root user because I am doing system admin jobs within the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"

[ $UID != 0 ] && exec sudo $0 "$@"

if [[ ! `rbenv version | grep "2.1.4"` ]]; then
    echo "rbenv not installed ... do something"
else
    echo "rbenv installed"
fi
```

However, when I run the script for the normal user context (using sudo):

```
user@aaabbbccc:~$ sudo ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 5: rbenv: command not found
rbenv not installed ... do something
```

Why is my script not picking up the context for the root user and detecting that `rbenv` is actually installed?

**Update: added Debug output**

```
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
++ grep 2.1.4
++ rbenv version
+ [[ ! -n '' ]]
+ echo 'rbenv not installed'
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @Cyrus ok, added debug output...

Comment: From what I can surmise, I'm not actually running `sudo -i` in my script, instead, just prepending `sudo` to commands, therefore my rbenv path isn't being loaded since I'm not actually loading the bash profile for the root user?

Comment: This is something better handled by package management, not run-time checks. Install `rbenv` from a package, and create a package for your script that requires `rbenv` to be installed.

Comment: If the sole purpose of the script is to determine if `rbenv` is installed, that's what package managers are for.

Comment: I suggest to use `dpkg -l PACKAGE_NAME` without sudo and use its returncode. See: [How do I check if a package is installed on my server?](http://askubuntu.com/q/423355/336375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/` (or wherever rbenv executable is installed) is not in your user's executable path when sudo runs. Use -i or add `/usr/local/` to your `$PATH`.